# Getting pixel location given its value

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

is it possible in matlab to get the location of a pixel(rows and column) if the value at that pixel location is known?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: @Roma, can u post the answer here or give a link to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the coordinates of the pixel

```
[y x] = find( grayImg == val, 1 ); %// find one pixel that has intensity val
```

For RGB image, you need three values

```
[y x] = find( rgbImg(:,:,1) == r_val & rgbImg(:,:,2) == g_val & rgbImg(:,:,3) == b_val, 1 )
```

---

In case of single precision image, one might find the comparison `==` too strict (see, e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab)). Therefore, a relaxed version can be applied:

```
thresh = 1e-5;
[row col] = find( abs( grayImg - val ) < thresh, 1 );
```

To find a pixel within `thresh` tolerance of `val`.

You may also try and find the pixel with value closest to `val`:

```
[~, lidx] = min( abs( grayImg(:) - val ) );
[row col] = ind2sub( size(grayImg), lidx );
```

Comment: @Roma are you certain there is a pixel with that value in your image? make sure your image values are in the same scale as the values you are searching for; For instance, if your image is of type `uint8` the values should be in range `0..255`

Comment: the type is single

Comment: using `==` with floating points can be tricky [see this thread for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab). you might need to relax the `==` condition or convert to `uint8` for comparisons.

Comment: what changes are supposed to be made in the code that you have provided?

Comment: @Roma what variant? the gray image or the rgb image?

Comment: how to modify it if the image is a complex image where real and imaginary parts are floating point in nature

Comment: @Roma you can combine the insights from single precision image and the RGB solutions

Comment: is it possible for me to convert the matlab code to scilab?